# Kubernetes Ingress Nginx not forwarding to Services

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, ingress-nginx

This is my ingress service config file.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-srv
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - host: products.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /list
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              service:
                name: products-srv
                port: 
                  number: 4000
```

Here, I am trying to pass all of my requests on `products.com/list` to the service `products-srv`. I've created a `ClusterIP` service as well.

After that, I've also added `127.0.0.1 products.com` to the `/etc/hosts` file.

My problem is: When I am trying to access the `products.com` with my browser, then it is showing a `404 Not Found` error. Anyone suggest me a solution please?

Comment: Let's start the debugging from the container > service > ingress
If you port-forward the pod, you can see the UI? If yes, if you port-forward the svc, you can see the UI? I think that if you will add the service and pod yaml it will be helpful.

Comment: What about `product.com/list`? This is what you have exposed in the ingress.